# Seaborn regplot: Point and line merged legend

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm using seaborn's regplot function to plot a series of grouped scatters alongside a linear fit for each. Everything works just fine, except that when I try to include a legend, it includes only a line for each group when what I really want is for the legend for each group to have the marker used for the scatter AND a line going through said marker. Is this possible? Here is an excerpt of what my code looks like for reference:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
legends = []
for group in groups:
    some_group_plot = sns.regplot(x='x', y='y', data=pd.DataFrame({'x': x_array,
                                                                   'y': y_array}),
                                  ci=None, color=next(palette),
                                  ax=ax,
                                  line_kws={'lw': 2},
                                  scatter=True, truncate=False)
    legends.append(group)
plt.legend(legends, fontsize=18)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some remarks:

- Seaborn relies on matplotlib for the legend. In matplotlib, the legends are created via the `label=` parameter in many of its functions.  Also `sns.regplot` accepts that parameter.
- `sns.regplot` returns the `ax` on which it has created the plot. As the `ax=` parameter is used, the variable `some_group_plot` will be just the same as the given `ax` and can be omitted.

Here is some example code, including the necessary library imports and some random data:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(123)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
groups = ['group 1', 'group 2', 'group 3']
for group in groups:
    sns.regplot(x='x', y='y', data=pd.DataFrame({'x': np.random.rand(5), 'y': np.random.rand(5)}),
                ci=None,
                ax=ax,
                line_kws={'lw': 2},
                scatter=True, truncate=False, label=group)
plt.legend(fontsize=10)
plt.show()
```

[image: seaborn regplots with legend]

If you also want a label for the regression line, you can add the `label` keyword to `line_kws`:

```py
for group in groups:
    sns.regplot(x='x', y='y', data=pd.DataFrame({'x': np.random.rand(5), 'y': np.random.rand(5)}),
                ci=None,
                ax=ax,
                line_kws={'lw': 2, 'label': 'Regression for ' + group},
                scatter=True, truncate=False, label=group)
plt.legend(fontsize=10, ncol=2)
```

To combine both markers, the newest matplotlib versions (tested with 3.4.2), allow [combining markers into tuples](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/legend_guide.html) and default plot them on top of each other. You can use `ax.get_legend_handles_labels()` to extract the existing handles for the legend and combine them.

```py
np.random.seed(123)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
groups = ['group 1', 'group 2', 'group 3']
for group in groups:
    sns.regplot(x='x', y='y', data=pd.DataFrame({'x': np.random.rand(5), 'y': np.random.rand(5)}),
                ci=None,
                ax=ax,
                line_kws={'lw': 2, 'label': 'Regression for ' + group},
                scatter=True, truncate=False, label=group)
handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
n = len(groups)
plt.legend(handles=[(h1, h2) for h1, h2 in zip(handles[:n], handles[n:])],
           labels=labels[n:],
           fontsize=10)
plt.show()
```

[image: legend with combined markers]

Comment: Absolutely, thank you very much! I have a follow-up: The legend markers are ever so slightly off-centre, which isn't an issue with circular markers, but will mask others, is there a way to align them with the lines properly? I can also notice that the line is placed in front of the marker, which I'd also like to rectify if this can be done.

Comment: To center the markers in the legend, you can use the extra parameter `plt.legend(..., scatteryoffsets=[0.5])` (the default is `0.375` when there is only one point).  To change the z-order, you can use `for h1 in handles[:n]: h1.set_zorder(1)`. Alternatively, if you also want to change the z-order of the main plot, you can add `sns.regplot(..., scatter_kws={'zorder':3})`